# How to configure database configuration connection pooling with custom prefix in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-boot, connection-pooling, spring-jdbc

Consider Spring Boot with `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` and that you would like to have one or more Data Sources, which do have a custom prefix in their property names. From what I see in `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration` it looks to me, that the auto-configuration can only be used with the default prefix `spring.datasource`, but as soon as you modify it, you will be on your own setting up the properties regarding pooling.

Can someone please shed light on how to configure the Tomcat JDBC Pool DataSource more elegant (read Spring idiomatic)?

**Current work around:**

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    @Value("${datasource.api.tomcat.maxWait:5000}")
    private int maxWaitMillis;

    @Value("${datasource.api.tomcat.test-on-borrow:true}")
    private boolean testOnBorrow;

    @Value("${datasource.api.tomcat.validation-query:SELECT 1}")
    private String validationQuery;

    @Bean(name = "apiDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.api")
    public DataSource apiDataSource() {
        DataSource ds = DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        // Assume we make use of Apache Tomcat connection pooling (default in Spring Boot)
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource tds = (org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) ds;
        tds.setTestOnBorrow(testOnBorrow);
        tds.setValidationQuery(validationQuery);
        tds.setMaxWait(maxWaitMillis);
        return ds;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it turned out to be quite straight-forward thanks to the binding feature of Spring Boot's `ConfigurationProperties` annotation, you can directly populate the JDBC connection pool properties in the following fashion and avoid therefore the cumbersome initialisation of each property on its own:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.api")
public PoolProperties apiPoolProperties() {
    return new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolProperties();
}

@Bean(name = "apiDataSource")
public DataSource apiDataSource(@Qualifier("apiPoolProperties") PoolProperties poolProperties) {
    DataSource ds = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource(poolProperties);
    logger.info("Initialized API Datasource: {}", ds);
    return ds;
}
```